# How do i remove tput color from log file

Tags: bash, sed, colors

I have a bash script which I have made the output pretty with colors and stuff, however my log file looks horrible.

If it can be modified before it is piped to the log file that would be preferable but if that is not possible i would like to at least run a clean-up function that could be run at the end of my script which would clean the log file of the ugliness.

I have tried things like `sed -r -i "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" install.log` but that did not seem to clean up

Below are the color variables used
`BOLD=$(tput bold);   RED=$(tput setaf 1);   WHITE=$(tput setaf 7);   BGBLUE=$(tput setab 4);   BGRED=$(tput setab 1);   RCol=$(tput sgr0);   InCol=$(tput rev);   UndLn=$(tput smul)
BWhiOn_Red=$BOLD$WHITE$BGRED;   BWhiOn_Blu=$BOLD$WHITE$BGBLUE;   BRed=$BOLD$RED;`

Here is an code snippet
`printf "%s\n" "${BRed}MISSION ABORTED! Abandon Ship!!${RCol}" | tee -a install.log`

And this is what it looks like when I vi the log file
`^[[1m^[[31mMISSION ABORTED! Abandon Ship!!^[(B^[[m`

When using `sed -r -i "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" install.log` the log file shows this
 `MISSION ABORTED! Abandon Ship!!^[(B`

It seems like the regex doesn't cover `tput sgr0` but i am not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sed -i -e 's/\x1B[^m]*m//g' install.log
```

To break down the sed command, the `\x1B` is the escape character that starts a control sequence: `Ctrl-[` .  A control sequence ends with an `m`, so we find every character that is NOT an m, and the m that follows: `[^m]*m`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem

```
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    BOLD=$(tput bold);
    RED=$(tput setaf 1)
    ...
fi
```

and the values won't be set if you redirecting to a file